# People Service ResolvePrincipals does not resolve SharePoint groups when the PrincipalType is All and SharePoint is using claims based authentication

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, groups, spprincipal

I'm updating some legacy code which relies on the People service.  SharePoint groups do not resolve on a webapplication in SP2013 with the authentication provider set to Claims Based Authentication and the PrincipalType set to all.  If I change the PrincipalType to SharePointGroup, it resolves correctly.  On a webapplication with NTLM authentication it resolves correctly with the PrincipalType set to all.  Is this a bug or working as intended?